# Nesting a button group within a button group in android?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, nested

i am fairly experienced at coding in java but i am just learning to build graphical user interfaces in android environment. I have searched alot for the answer to this question but i wonder if im not searching for the right thing?

I want to be able to choose between 2 radio buttons, and if the first of these radio buttons is chosen then a group of 2 more radio buttons should be chosen from. Its hard to explain exactly what i mean so i hope this helps.....

1. Choice One

   ```
         1.a choice one a

         1.b choice one b
   ```
2. Choice Two

So, if 'choice one' is picked then the user MUST pick from choices 1a OR 1b,  whereas if the user picks 'choice two' then the sub options (1a and 1b) are not even available (greyed out i suppose).

I thought i could just nest one RadioGroup inside another, but it doesnt seem to work this way.

If anybody can help me here id be really grateful.

Comment: can you elaborate on what exactly is not working?

Comment: well i can get a radio group working for 2 buttons, obviously, simple. but i essentially want another 2 choices available if i pick the first one, so effectively there are 3 choices...1a, 1b or 2. i have no idea how to nest this. i tried adding a seccond group to the frist radio button but that just gives rendering errors and the whole user interface preview in android studio disappears

Comment: i suppose what i really need to know is.... is it actually possible to have a radio button group that has another button group inside to select from when a particular choice is made? And how would i achieve a simple version of this?

Comment: Hi, i don't know what is wrong with me haha; i seem to have just done it =) I can't believe how many hours ive spent trying to figure this out when it seems that it is achieved by doing exactly what i had originally attempted to do. I think i litterally pasted my copy of my original button group into the wrong place and didnt realise!

Answer (score 0):

you could create a popup and fill the data on OnCLickListener and then display it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you trying to use show() and hide() for radio button? maybe using a boolean for the parameter show() and hide()